# Bash - How to capture both foreground and background process logs in bash

Tags: bash, logging

I'm running a few tasks on the same terminal in bash. Is there a way I can stream all the logs I'm seeing on the bash terminal to a log file? I know can technically pipe the logs of individual tasks, but wondering if there's a more elegant way. So far this is what I'm doing:

```
$> python background1.py > logs/bg1.log & \
   python background2.py > logs/bg2.log & \
   python foreground.py | tee logs/fg.log
```

Is there a way I can somehow capture everything together? (somewhat similar to how CI/CD tools show all of the terminal output in the browser).

Comment: Include a [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by everything together, but perhaps this will help you

```
   ( python background1.py & python background2.py & python foreground.py ) | tee logs/one.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do:

```
nohup python background1.py >> logs/log.log & 2>&1 
nohup python background2.py >> logs/log.log & 2>&1 
nohup python foreground.py >> logs/log & 2>&1
```

That way, all log output will go into the same logfile.
Is this what you mean?